# Is there a way to get a stable unique identifier for a U2F device using the Web Authentication API (WebAuthn)?

Tags: javascript, authentication, firefox, yubico, webauthn

I would like to build an authentication system where a user can not provide any information (no username, email, etc.) and simply use their U2F device to identify themselves as well as authenticate.

From what I can tell from looking at the [Web Authentication API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API), it appears that the U2F device will create a new public key every time [create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CredentialsContainer/create) or [get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CredentialsContainer/get) is called.

Is there a way to get a stable id from a U2F device that can be used for identification?

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not work. Because U2F can be used with multiple identities.
WebAuthn proves that you are a specific identity. So you have to provide this information.